# Creating a Complete WEB MSN Application Like EBuddy. First Steps [?]

Tags: php, msn

I want to create an application like that in my website, I want to be able to login (without that Microsoft Permission like in Ebuddy), chat with people, see groups, block contacts and everything that EBuddy is able to do.

I don't think that the Live Developer thing on the Microsoft let us do that. (Does it ?)

So What should I have to do. if it was an online thing it would be easier but since a windows application, it gets really hard.

Where do I start? I want to write it in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: so do you want it in the web (like ebuddy) or native?

Comment: in the web, the same way, I just want to know how to retrieve the information as text, like the contacts, whos online, the groups, and then I can parse myself and build the application. the problem is how to connect, where to start.

Comment: well for that you will have to use MSN's APIs which obviously includes 'Microsoft Permission like in Ebuddy'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is one good example from Microsoft with PHP and Javascript.But I don't know good doc.You can download it from I give you to Chat Im sample [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=messengerconnect&DownloadId=12970) .You can look the details from [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/messengerconnect/).I think you can do it that way.Also look at [JwChat](http://blog.jwchat.org/jwchat/).